# Is there a way to update a database field based on a list?

Tags: jpa, playframework

Using JPA, I have a list of entries from my database :

```
User(id, firstname, lastname, email)
```

That I get by doing:

```
List<User> users = User.find("lastname = ?", "smith");
```

And I'd like to update all in one request, by doing something like this :

```
"UPDATE USER SET email = null IN :list"
```

and then set the parameter "list" to `users`

Is it possible? if so, how?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could embed the query that you used to obtain list in the where clause of the update.

```
UPDATE User a SET a.email = null 
WHERE user IN (SELECT b FROM User b WHERE lastName = :?)
```

By doing this you'd be doing the query to search the list and the update in single update query.

How do you like that? Do you think this could work?

**-EDIT-**

Since you want to use the original list of items instead of a list just retrieved from the database, you can still ensure you build the original list like this

```
UPDATE User a SET a.email = null 
WHERE user IN (SELECT b FROM User b WHERE lastName IN(:originalList))
```

Then when you invoke it, you can do something like this:

```
Collection<String> originalList = Arrays.asList("Kenobi", "Skywalker", "Windu");
query.setParameter("originalList", originalList);
```

By this, you can still ensure the query will only contain items in your original list and not any possible new item from the database, provided that that last name is a candidate key in the database, otherwise I would recommend that you use the ID for the subquery instend of the last name.

Comment: The problem is that the list of USers I retrive can change with the time, and I'm affraid that the Update would affect those changes. I want to keep the update for the currently selected users.

Comment: @cx42net You can still use the original list as a parameter for the query. I have updated the post to show an example of how I believe it could be done.

Comment: Works like a charm! Perfect! I started to do the same way, using a `String[]`, but the IN(:list) wasn't working, I had to do a `join(",", names)` and that wasn't pretty at all! Your solution is way better! Thanks!

Comment: But I was thinking, I did a change to your code because `WHERE lastname IN (:originalList)` will result in `WHERE lastname IN("smith", "smith", "smith")`. The update really use the ID : `WHERE id IN (:originalList)`, and the list is a simple `List<Long>` of collected ids.

Comment: @cx42net d(^_^)b That's why I said the where filter should use a candidate key, like the ID.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jpa+hibernate you can use entityManager.createQuery() for creating hql query
like that:

```
String hql = "UPDATE Supplier SET name = :newName WHERE name IN :name";
entityManager.createQuery(hql);
```

Comment: Ok I finally tested it, and it doesn't work. The list "name" is a list of Supplier instance, not a list of String. Based on that, the request fails because it expect a list of Strings and not a list of Suppliers.

Comment: and besides if using JPA then em.createQuery is for JPQL not HQL.